# ASP MVC Bootstrap Modal in Partial View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

As part of my shared layout, I'd like to have a modal dialog come up on a button click.

This is the my partial view with the modal dialog:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <button type="button" class="open-dialog btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SettingsModal">Settings</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="SettingsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="SettingsModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a id="settings" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function() {
        $('#settings').attr('href', $(this).data('url')); // update the link's url
    });
</script>
```

And the partial view's controller:

```
public class SettingsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult _Settings()
    {
        return PartialView("_Settings");
    }
}
```

What I'm going for, is to have a button at the top of the page as part of the shared _Layout. Similar to this:

[image]

When I click the 'Settings' button, a modal dialog is supposed to come up, but when I click it now, the screen just goes dark, and I can sort of hint the modal dialog in the background. I'm not sure where in the modal I've done something wrong. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: you have to send ajax call to action

Comment: are you missing the ending `</div>` for `<div id="SettingsModal" />` or did you just leave it out?

Comment: have you included the partial in your view with `@Html.Partial` ?

Comment: I would suggest this approach http://jsfiddle.net/9hq1xepz/

Comment: @Shehary beat me to it, working plunkr example here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7BMhYD5UP2QoaNTGWmcc?p=preview) I only change the button text but you should get the idea. At a guess you may be missing the bootstrap.js or bootstrap.css references or as JamieD77 eluded to you may have some duff HTML?

Comment: @JamieD77 Hmm, I have checked a couple times and I'm pretty sure it's there.
Shehary Even if I use your code, I get the same problem. The modal window is there, but it's *behind* the faded screen, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Dandy I've included it the same way that 'Register' and 'Log in' are included in the shared _Layout file: 
`@Html.Partial("_Settings")`

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: @JB06 I popped up the console and noticed a "$ is not defined" error. "Of course" I thought and included jQuery, which made it go away. But my problem still persists..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#settings').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        url = button.data('url');
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            $('.model-body').html(data);
        });
});
```

Action method:

```
public PartialViewResult Settings()
{
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // retrive your model
                return PartialView("_Settings");
            }
            return null;
}
```